# How index starts with 1 in revel Framework

Tags: arrays, go, revel, array-indexing

```
  <tr>
      <td>rank</td>
      <td>abc</td>
  </tr>
  {{ range $index,$abc := .abc }}
     <tr>
      <td>{{$index}}</td> // 0
      <td>{{$abc}}</td>
     </tr>
  {{end}}
```

> 1. how to {{$index}} starts with 1
>
>    {{add $index 1}} - unction "add" not defined
>
>    {{$index + 1}}   - illegal number syntax: "+"

Comment: Have you try passing your own `add` function to the template data?

Comment: You can assign a variable "add" to your controller's [ViewArgs](https://godoc.org/github.com/revel/revel#Controller.ViewArgs) that returns a +1 value of the input number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a custom function into your controller's [ViewArgs](https://godoc.org/github.com/revel/revel#Controller.ViewArgs) as a variable.

```golang
controller.ViewArgs["addOne"] = func (i int64) {
    return i+1
}
```

You can then use `$.addOne` to access the function in a loop. To use it as a function, you have to add a `call` keyword before it:

```golang
  <tr>
      <td>rank</td>
      <td>abc</td>
  </tr>
  {{ range $index, $abc := .abc }}
     <tr>
      <td>{{call $.addOne $index}}</td> // $index + 1
      <td>{{$abc}}</td>
     </tr>
  {{end}}
```